# Mount persistent disk with data to VM without formatting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, persistent-storage

I am trying to mount a persistent disk with data to a VM to use it in Google Datalab. So far no success, ideally I would like to see my files in the Datalab notebook.

First, I added the disk in VM settings with Read/Write mode.

Second, I ran $lsblk to see what disks there are.

Then tried this: sudo mount -o ro /dev/sdd    /mnt/disks/z

I got this error:

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd,
```

P.S. I used the disk I want to mount on another VM and downloaded some data on it. It was formatted as NTFS disk.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would need to create a file system as noted in the [following document](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/mkpart.html)

`$ mkfs.vfat /dev/sdX2`

Creates a new partition, without creating a new file system on that partition.

`Command: mkpart [part-type fs-type name] start end`